# Restarting Partition Step in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Our application is a Spring batch running in `openshift`. The application calls another service via REST to fetch records from database. Both use `nginx` side car for handling the traffic. Both side cars restarted for some reason and the Spring batch job terminated suddenly .I already implemented retry mechanism using `@Retryable` but the logic has not even reached the retry part. The only log I found in the application is given below

```
"Encountered an error executing step myPartitionStep in job myJob","level":"ERROR","thread":"main","logClass":"o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep","logMethod":"execute","stack_trace":"o.s.b.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step
o.s.b.c.p.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:112)
o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
o.s.b.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152)
o.s.b.c.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
o.s.b.c.j.f.s.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68)
o.s.b.c.j.f.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
o.s.b.c.j.f.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
o.s.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137)
o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320)
o.s.b.c.l.s.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149)
o.s.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
o.s.b.c.l.s.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140)
j.i.r.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java)
j.i.r.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
j.i.r.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
o.s.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
o.s.a.f.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
o.s.a.f.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
o.s.b.c.c.a.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
... 13 frames truncated\n"
```

I am not able to point what exactly is the reason for this error. It stopped at `partition` step which uses `itemReader` to call another service and fetche the records,`FlatFileItemWriter` which writes the records. We cannot afford to have duplicates in our file. Is it possible to restart the  app exactly where it stopped without having duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace you shared is truncated, so it is not possible to see the root cause from what you shared.

Spring Batch supports restarting a failed partitioned step, as long as you use a persistent job repository. You need to restart the same job instance, ie use the same job parameter that you used in your first run (that failed). Only failed partitions will be rerun. Any failed partition will resume from where it left off.

Comment: hi Mahmoud, Do you have any page or blog where restorability in partitions is explained in better way. I would like to understand how that works? Does SB tables stores all the failed partitions with record where it left?

Comment: The way it works is that Spring Batch creates a step execution for each partition, so when you restart the same job instance (by using the same parameters), it will detect which partitions failed and restart only the failed ones. You can find some examples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/samples/partition. Try to change them to make some partition fails and see how it works.